# Mongoid Rails - Is there a way to check the field's datatype before saving?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, before-save

I have this class `ProfitLoss` which consists of these fields. I want to call this method `zero_if_blank` on `before_validation` as `before_save` is not working and what i want to do is assign 0 to those values which are blank and are of `Integer` when coming from the form. **I searched a lot like the Mysql `columns_hash` but didn't find any method to give the type of each field in mongo**.

```
class ProfitLoss < Generic
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include MongoMysqlRelations

  field :fiscal_year, type: String
  field :sales_excluding_other_incomes, type: Integer
  field :other_incomes, type: Integer
  field :closing_stock, type: Integer

  before_validation :zero_if_blank

  def zero_if_blank
    pp self.columns_hash.each {|k,v| puts "#{k} => #{v.type}"}
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried `field :other_incomes, type: Integer, default: 0`?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I have used that but on the Form input, it shows 0 for all the integer fields so i dont want to use that.

Comment: You should be able to set [defaults](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-documents/#defaults) on the field as @SergioTulentsev pointed out. As the manual pointed out `You can tell a field in Mongoid to always have a default value if nothing has been provided`. If it behaves differently, you should check your form and what values it returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this piece of code did the work :)

```
def zero_if_blank 
  self.fields.each do |k,v|
   if v.type == Integer && self.attributes[k] == nil
     self.__send__("#{k}=", 0)
   end
  end
end
```